# When calling prepareForReuse() in CustomTableViewCell.swift, UITableViewCells become unresponsive after several deletions from UITableView (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app that pulls objects from Firebase, then displays them in a table. I've noticed that if I delete 5 entries (this is about when I get to the reused cells that were deleted), I can't delete any more (red delete button is unresponsive) & can't even select the cells. This behavior stops when I comment out `override func prepareForReuse()` in the TableViewCell.swift controller. Why???

The rest of the app functions normally while the cells are just unresponsive. Weirdly, if I hold one finger on a cell and tap the cell with another finger, I can select the cell. Then, if I hold a finger on the cell and tap the delete button, that cell starts acting normally again. What is happening here??? Here is my code for the table & cells:

In CustomTableViewCell.swift >>

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    // CELLS STILL FREEZE EVEN WHEN THE FOLLOWING LINE IS COMMENTED OUT?!?!
    cellImage.image = nil
}
```

In ViewController.swift >>

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadUserThings()
}

func loadUserThings() {
    ref.child("xxx").child(user!.uid).child("yyy").queryOrdered(byChild: "aaa").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // A CHANGE WAS DETECTED. RELOAD DATA.
        self.arr = []
        for tempThing in snapshot.children {
            let thing = Thing(snapshot: tempThing as! DataSnapshot)
            self.arr.append(thing)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let cellData = arr[indexPath.row]
    ...
    // SET TEXT VALUES OF LABELS IN THE CELL
    ...
    // Setting image to nil in CustomTableViewCell
    let imgRef = storageRef.child(cellData.imgPath)
    let activityIndicator = MDCActivityIndicator()
    // Set up activity indicator
    cell.cellImage.sd_setImage(with: imgRef, placeholderImage: nil, completion: { (image, error, cacheType, ref) in
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        delay(time: 0.2, function: {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                cell.cellImage.alpha = 1
            })
        })
    })
    if cell.cellImage.image == nil {
        cell.cellImage.alpha = 0
    }
    // Seems like sd_setImage doesn't always call completion block if the image is loaded quickly, so we need to stop the loader before a bunch of activity indicators build up
    delay(time: 0.2) {
        if cell.cellImage.image != nil {
            activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            cell.cellImage.alpha = 1
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // instantly deselect row to allow normal selection of other rows
    tableView.deselectRow(at: tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!, animated: false)
    selectedObjectIndex = indexPath.row
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "customSegue", sender: self)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        print("should delete")
        let row = indexPath.row
        let objectToDelete = userObjects[row]
        userObjects.remove(at: row)
        ref.child("users/\(user!.uid)/objects/\(objectToDelete.nickname!)").removeValue()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle {
    if (self.tableView.isEditing) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete
    }
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyle.none
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A few things. For performance reasons, you should only use `prepareForReuse` to  reset attributes that are related to the appearance of the cell and not content (like images and text). Set content like text and images in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate of your tableView and reset cell appearance attributes like alpha, editing, and selection state in `prepareForReuse`. I am not sure why it continues to behave badly when you comment out that line and leave `prepareForReuse` empty because so long as you are using a custom table view cell an empty `prepareForReuse` should not affect performance. I can only assume it has something to do with you not invoking the superclass implementation of `prepareForReuse`, which is required by Apple according to the docs:

```
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        // CELLS STILL FREEZE EVEN WHEN THE FOLLOWING LINE IS COMMENTED OUT?!?!
         super.prepareForReuse()
    }
```

The `prepareForReuse` method is only ever intended to do minor cleanup for your custom cell.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Adding `super.prepareForReuse()` fixed the freezing.

Comment: Should we call super on the end or beginning of the function?

Comment: @GergelyKovacs at the beginning